# Evaluating Sided Limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let the function $f:D\subseteq \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{x^n}{2+x^n}$

Evaluate the given limits:

$(a) \lim_{x\to -1^{-}}$ $f(x)$

$(b) \lim_{x\to -1^{+}}$ $f(x)$

$(c) \lim_{x\to 1^{-}}$ $f(x)$

$(d) \lim_{x\to 1^{+}}$ $f(x)$

We are in a section proving sided limits and this is a homework question. Honestly, I have never seen a function equal to the limit of a function. I don't understand how to evaluate this at all. We did not go over anything like this. 
I do know
$\lim_{n\to \infty} x^n= 0$ for $|x|<1$, which really confused me further. 
Can I just get instructions or intuition on how to evaluate?

Comment: i would discover the cases $$|x|=1,-1<x<1,x>1,x<-1$$

Comment: So I am taking the limit of a limit? basically composition?

Comment: all These cases must you consider

Comment: What is $D?\,\,$

Comment: So $a=0$ is an accumulation point of D?